# Create multiple triggers in scheduled task

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, task-scheduler

Server 2012

I have an existing scheduled task that I would like to add multiple triggers to.

I do this:

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 1PM -Once
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Task Name" -Trigger $trigger
```

It will overwrite the trigger that is already in there.

However, I want to create multiple triggers.

I try this:

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Once -At 1PM 
Add-JobTrigger -Trigger $trigger -Name "Task Name"
```

and this:

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 1PM
Add-JobTrigger -Trigger $trigger -Name "Task Name"
```

In both cases, I get the error "A scheduled job definition with Name Task Name could not be found" (There is a task there called "Task Name")

What do I need to do to simply add multiple triggers to a single task?

Comment: To be clear, do you want the job to start after either trigger fires or after both triggers fire?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-Trigger` parameter can take an array of `ScheduledJobTrigger` objects so for your example you can do.

```
$trigger = @(
    $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 1PM -Once),
    $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 2PM -Once),
    $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 3PM -Once)
)
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Task Name" -Trigger $trigger
```

The same is valid with `Add-JobTrigger` too.

```
$trigger = @(
    $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 1PM -Once),
    $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 2PM -Once),
    $(New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 3PM -Once)
)
Add-JobTrigger -Trigger $trigger -Name "Task Name"
```

Comment: is this possible to do via schtasks command? I tried schtasks /change /tn mytaskname /st 03:00 /sd 2020/10/20 /sc once   and command succeeded but it didn't create any new trigger for the task

Comment: Yes and no. It is not possible to do using parameters like you are trying here but you can with a scheduled task XML file and pass that in with `/xml`. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/working-with-task-scheduler-xml/

Comment: meanwhile I figured out a powershell way with New-ScheduledTaskTrigger, New-CimSession and Set-ScheduledTask, but I am afraid it might have a problem with some older powershell versions...